# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python\\Scripts'

Tags: django

I'm self-learning the Django and following the 'writing your first Django app' tutorial. I can start new projects. but when I ran

```
    ...\> py manage.py runserver
```

to check the project. [ModeleNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7KoX.jpg) occurs.
It says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\Python\Scripts'
 I have no idea why this is happening. It used to work well until this happened recently. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but got the same error.

Comment: which python and django version you are using ?

Comment: python 3.8  django 3.0